# Accessing Value Returned from getPosition?

Tags: java, android

I know this is probably as basic as questions can get, but I don't see a direct answer anywhere after looking. How do you access a value returned from a function like getPosition? I know how to set it up, but I don't know how to see what the result is. Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Mike

Sorry about not posting code initially. I thought it might not be necessary, but I see now I should have:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
Spinner spinner, spinner1, platform_spinner;
Button button1, home_button;
EditText editText1, editText2, editText3;

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

Double priceInput = (double) 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_db_button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    home_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_button);
    home_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Find first spinner
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    // Populate first spinner

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.genre_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Bind adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition("Strategy"));
```

What I am trying to do is to get the value that will be generated from the last line for getPosition as a way of determining which item in the spinner was chosen.

Comment: Show us your code.  What are you trying to write? What _exactly_ don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your getPosition is declared as

```
public int getPosition(int someArgument)
{
    int result;
    // Do some stuff
    return result;
}
```

Then you get your value as:

```
int myPostition = getPosition(15); // Assuming that 15 is a meaningful argument for your method
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! So, it looks like I need to setup a method to retrieve the value...

Comment: Well, if you want some method do something, you first have to create it, don't you?